# better idiom for selecting id of single record matched using alternative primary key?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Say I have a model Foo with normal integer primary key (id) and an "alternate" primary key "bar" that's a string.

To complicate matters, Foo supports soft deletes, so it has a boolean property "is_deleted".  "bar" is unique only over the set of records where is_deleted = false.

I want to find the integer id of the single non-deleted row where bar = "baz", or nil if there is no such row.  Below is what I came up with:

```
Foo.where(bar: 'baz', is_deleted: false).limit(1).pluck(:id).first
```

That seems ickily verbose.  Is there a better way?  Modifying the underlying database is not an option.  I'm free to alter the model class, so long as it doesn't interfere with other code that uses this model.

Comment: You should look into [`scopes`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes). While you can't reduce the query as such (you have conditions that need to be defined), you can put that whole thing into the `Foo` model with a scope. Then you get a nice name and can do something like `Foo.first_active`.

Comment: You shouldn't need to limit to one record, but check if there is more than one and return an error of some kind.